Return a fixed pointer ref in C#
I want to know if it is safe for the RepeatedIDValue64_8.Get method in the following code to return a reference to a certain memory segment after forcing a fixed pointer? A crash occurred in our program, and I want to know if it is related to the memory defragmentation after GC?
public struct IDValue64 : IStructMessage<IDValue64>
{
    public static StructMessageParser<IDValue64> Parser = new StructMessageParser<IDValue64>();
    public const int SizeOf = 16;
    public long Id;
    public long Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat();
        format.WriteLine("{");
        format.Indent();
        format.WriteLine("Id : " + Id.ToString() + ",");
        format.WriteLine("Value : " + Value.ToString() + " }");
        format.Outdent();
        return format.ToString();
    }

}


unsafe public struct RepeatedIDValue64_8 
{
    const int BuffSize = 128;
    public const int MaxCount = 8;
    public int Count;
    public fixed byte Buffer[BuffSize];
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return Count;
    }
    public int GetMaxCount()
    {
        return MaxCount;
    }
    public ref IDValue64 Get(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= Count)
        {
            string message = string.Format("class RepeatedIDValue64_8 index{0} count{1}", index, Count);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message);
        }
        fixed (byte* pb = Buffer)
        {
            IDValue64* pbs = (IDValue64*)pb;
            return ref pbs[index]; // is safe?
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("{\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("[" + i.ToString() + "]:");
            sb.Append(Get(i).ToString());    // core pos
        }
        sb.Append('}');
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

dotnet version is 8.0
this is coredump clrstack
clrstack

As far as I know, the scope of the "fixed" will end the moment it leaves the method. So the pointer value is no longer valid. I just don't see the relationship between ref span[index] and that pointer.

The act of coercing an unmanaged pointer to a managed pointer inside a fixed region is fine, I believe; however, it can lead to scenarios where you leak an interior pointer outside of the stack-frame that semantically owns that managed pointer, in ways that the compiler cannot warn about. I could very easily believe that such an error has occurred somewhere. For example, returning the ref from a method, where the ref points to somewhere inside the stackframe being exited.

why do we need the fixed at all if we are returning a managed pointer?
return ref pbs[index]; without fixed should return a managed pointer that the GC cares about to update.

First, an aside,
public fixed byte Buffer[BuffSize];

Doesn't make Buffer fixed in memory, it makes lays out the array in the struct's memory, rather than in its own memory block.
But to the point, in a fixed statement:
fixed (byte* pb = Buffer)
{
    IDValue64* pbs = (IDValue64*)pb;
    return ref span[index]; // is safe?
}

the fixing in memory (block from GC relocations) only applies while executing that block. When the containing function returns the block is exited and the GC can relocate Buffer (or, as per above, the struct containing Buffer).
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/fixed

You can use the declared pointer only inside the corresponding fixed statement. The declared pointer is readonly and can't be modified:


PE. the recent deep dive into Span<T> on the .NET channel covers how Span<T> is able to do similar things safely: https://youtu.be/5KdICNWOfEQ?si=FOFdI4ksZLVR1Vpd

First of all, thank you for your answer!!
ChatGPT asked me to modify it as follows, is it feasible?
fixed (byte* pb = Buffer)
{
var pbs = new Span<IDValue32>(pb, Count);
// IDValue32* pbs = (IDValue32*)pb;
return ref pbs[index];
}


The Span<T> can use pointers, but doesn't need in this case, you can pass the byte array also.

@Next66 that has the same problem. If you want a reference into a struct you have to use make that struct a  ref struct` (with all the restrictions that brings). Perhaps you should explain (in the question) what problem you have that you think can be solved with a ref return? (Ie. this sounds like an XY Problem.)

This code is generated by a protobuf protocol parser that we implemented in the development of the game server. The purpose of using a structure is to reduce the pressure of GC. The purpose of returning ref is to make it more convenient to use. If you return a pointer, you must add fixed when using it, which is very inconvenient.

Do you have some reference to the usage of fixed in declaration? All I can find is fixed scoped statement.

@greenoldman https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#fixed-size-buffers (is linked from the bottom of the fixed statement page).

It looks like the fixed statement is used just to avoid the compiler error:
CS1666 You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement.

End goal seems to be to index into the buffer but for it to be "safe", we need to return a managed pointer. We can certainly do it using a Span like this
public ref IDValue64 Get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= Count) {
        string message = string.Format("class RepeatedIDValue64_8 index{0} count{1}", index, Count);
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message);
    }
        
    fixed (byte* pb = Buffer) {
        var span = new Span<IDValue64>(pb, MaxCount);
        return ref span[index];
    }
}

but I think the original implementation
 fixed (byte* pb = Buffer)
    {
        IDValue64* pbs = (IDValue64*)pb;
        return ref pbs[index]; // is safe?
    }

achieves just the same. We are doing pointer arithmetic in both cases and we are converting a pinned at the time unmanaged pointer to a managed pointer. The managed part is that the GC is aware of it and should memory be compacted/moved it will update the address that is stored inside.
As long as our code does NOT depend on the managed pointer being fixed in memory AFTER we have returned from Get, everything should work out.
If it does we can make use of the fixed-pattern (examples) by implementing GetPinnableReference() on the RepeatedIDValue64_8 and then use fixed from the code that depends on our object being pinned in memory before calling Get.
EDIT:
It's also possible (as per Marc Gravell's comment) for something like this to be "safely" happening via Span (same result with the original pointer solution).
void Main() {
    ref var local = ref StackCreated();
    Console.WriteLine(local.innerField); // 0 - on stackframe we just returned from
    Console.WriteLine(local.innerField); // not 0 any longer since Console.WriteLine call create new stackframe

    ref var heap = ref HeapCreated();
    Console.WriteLine(heap.innerField); // 0
    Console.WriteLine(heap.innerField); // 0

}

ref IDValue64 StackCreated() {
    var composite = new RepeatedIDValue64_8(); // creates on the stack
    return ref composite.Get(0);
}

ref IDValue64 HeapCreated() {
    GetInterface composite = new RepeatedIDValue64_8(); // boxes
    return ref composite.Get(0);
}


// for boxing purposes
public interface GetInterface {
    public ref IDValue64 Get(int index);
}

public struct IDValue64 {
    public int innerField;
}

unsafe struct RepeatedIDValue64_8 : GetInterface {
    public fixed byte Buffer[32];
    public ref IDValue64 Get(int index) {
        fixed (byte* pb = Buffer) {
            var spanSolution = new Span<IDValue64>(pb, 8);
            return ref spanSolution[index];
            //
            // same results with "old" solution
            //IDValue64* pbs = (IDValue64*)pb;
            //return ref pbs[index];
        }
    }
}


Now there is no problem using it on the stack, but once this struct is allocated on the heap, occasional crashes will occur

@Next66 Since memory can be both on the stack and the heap with you need to familiarize yourself very well with Memory (concepts of owning memory) as well. If you understand all the implications you are better suited to write less bug-prone code. This is a great resource https://gist.github.com/GrabYourPitchforks/4c3e1935fd4d9fa2831dbfcab35dffc6#owners-consumers-and-lifetime-management
